# Global symbol definition error while using Net::OpenSSH with subs::parallel

Tags: perl

I have a sub routine that I need to run in parallel.  It uses Net::OpenSSH but OpenSSH.pm itself is throwing the "Global symbol 'X' requires explicit package name" error.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to run:

main.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
require './open.pl';

&OSSH;
```

open.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use subs::parallel;
use Net::OpenSSH;

sub OSSH : Parallel {
    my $SSH = Net::OpenSSH->new("localhost",
            user => 'root'
            );
}
1;
```

Errors:

```
Not enough arguments for subs::parallel::ref at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1274, near "ref,"
syntax error at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1295, near "_array_or_scalar_to_list delete"
Global symbol "%opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1296.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1299.
Global symbol "%opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1300.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1303.
Global symbol "%opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1304.
Global symbol "%opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1307.
Global symbol "@ssh_opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @ssh_opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1310.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1310.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1313.
Global symbol "%opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1313.
Global symbol "%opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1315.
Global symbol "@ssh_opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @ssh_opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1317.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1318.
Global symbol "@ssh_opts" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @ssh_opts"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1318.
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $self"?) at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1324.
syntax error at /home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm line 1328, near "}"
/home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm has too many errors.
Compilation failed in require at ./open.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./open.pl line 5.
Compilation failed in require at ./main.pl line 4.
```

Comment: A quick fix would be to replace the `ref,` in `Net::OpenSSH` with `{ ref $_ }` (just do that if you want it running now, and potentially not for a long time). The documentation of `subs::parallel` says `C<GLOBAL::CORE::ref> is overriden. This may be an issue if there are other modules in use which override it too. In the future, there may be a switch to disable this.`. I've looked in the code but I couldn't find this feature implemented (meaning that this "future" hasn't happen yet).

Comment: And if you are curious about why this happens: `subs::parallel` overrides `CORE::GLOBAL::ref` and adds a prototype to it (`($)`). However, `ref` can usually be called without arguments, and it then operates on `$_`. However, the prototype doesn't allow for `ref` to be called without arguments. And that's what `Net::OpenSSH` does, hence the error "Not enough arguments...".

Comment: @Dada I looked in OpenSSH.pm and I'm not sure where/how to replace `ref`.  Also, what are the side effects of doing this for long term use?

Comment: In `/home/chip/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/OpenSSH.pm`, the line contains `grep ref, @_`: replace it with `grep { ref $_ } @_`. About long term use: I don't really know how Perl modules are updated, but I'd expect that an update would undo that modification. Also, I can't be 100% sure that `subs::parallel` if fully compatible with `Net::OpenSSH` or any other modules... I was expecting for someone more experienced to come around a suggest a solution.

Comment: Have you considered using [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel) which also allows you to run multiple SSH operations in parallel and is a mature and tested solution?